# Request Read Receipt on Email when useing smtpserver

Tags: vb.net, smtp

I was sucessful in sending email using smtpserver. I am writing a VB.Net application.

My current code is:

```
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(mEMailUser, mEMailPassword) 
    SmtpServer.Port = 587 
    SmtpServer.Host = mHostName 
    mail = New MailMessage() 
    mail.From = New MailAddress(mFromEMail) 
    mail.To.Add(mfrmSendAnEmail.txtTo.Text) 
    mail.Subject = mfrmSendAnEmail.txtSubject.Text 

    _Attachment = mDirectory & "\" & gcloGlobals.DocumentName & ".pdf" 
    Dim oAttch As Attachment = New Attachment(_Attachment) 
    mail.Attachments.Add(oAttch) 

    mail.Body = mfrmSendAnEmail.txtBody.Text 
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

I want the Recipient to get a read request notification so that when they open the email they will have the option of sending the sender a notification that it was read.

I thought this might work:

```
  mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess
```

but it didn't.

Comment: I used mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure Or DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess, is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use:

```
message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "\"" + fromAddress.DisplayName + "\" <" + fromAddress.Address + ">");
```

In your code you don't set a display name for the from address, so you should use the simpler form instead of the line given above:

```
message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", mFromEMail);
```